# Which influence will cause SOA loss?

Tags: dns

Currently a certain domain has both **SOA** and **SPF** records in its DNS. In the new VPS, SOA and SPF record editing is not supported.

What are the consequences of losing this functionality?
(Especially SOA, because, as I understand, SPF is not relevant currently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpretting your question to be... **What would be affected by an inability to edit the SOA record in DNS ?** , and from the body of your question I'm assuming that you have a facility to edit some DNS records within a customer portal for some VPS system somewhere, but not **SOA** or **SPF**.

If this accurately reflects your intended question, then...

---

The **Start of Authority (SOA)** record allows a zone file to communicate administrative information about the zone contents, particularly: an administrative point of contact, a serial number potentially indicating change of content, and the REFRESH, RETRY, EXPIRY, and TTL time periods of the information. None of this information would usually be of direct interest or importance to you as a user, and would usually be administered by the operators of the underlying Domain Name Services (BIND or similar). Presumably the portal you use will automatically take care of incrementing the SERIAL when changes are made, and although you may have an interest in the various time periods, they are likely to be of more importance to the loading of your host than the functionality of your domain name.

...So I would suggest that you lose very little by not being able to edit the **SOA** record.

---

The **Sender Policy Framework (SPF)** has a deprecated **SPF** record type, and has been largely replaced by publishing the same information in a **TXT** record. Originally your VPS portal may have allowed / supported the direct **SPF** record type, and maybe you are referring to an inability to create those ? If so, just use the same content in a **TXT** record.

However if you genuinely can't create and administer SPF content in any way at all, then you do have a problem. The mitigation of abuse of your email domain, and more importantly, the perceived reputation of your genuine emails, is greatly impacted by the use of **SPF** along with **DKIM** and **DMARC**.

...So I would be surprised if you genuinely can't administer **SPF**, but very concerned if that is the case.